# MATLAB operators as functions

Tags: matlab

I was just curious that whether all operators in MATLAB are internally implemented as functions? We have equivalent functions for almost all MATLAB operators. `plus` for `+`, `minus` for `-`, `eq` for `==` and `transpose` for `'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most operators are represented by functions, yes.

A thorough list is provided on the MathWorks page [Implementing Operators for Your Class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/implementing-operators-for-your-class.html), reproduced here:

```
a + b               plus(a,b)         Binary addition
a - b               minus(a,b)        Binary subtraction
-a                  uminus(a)         Unary minus
+a                  uplus(a)          Unary plus
a.*b                times(a,b)        Element-wise multiplication
a*b                 mtimes(a,b)       Matrix multiplication
a./b                rdivide(a,b)      Right element-wise division
a.\b                ldivide(a,b)      Left element-wise division
a/b                 mrdivide(a,b)     Matrix right division
a\b                 mldivide(a,b)     Matrix left division
a.^b                power(a,b)        Element-wise power
a^b                 mpower(a,b)       Matrix power
a < b               lt(a,b)           Less than
a > b               gt(a,b)           Greater than
a <= b              le(a,b)           Less than or equal to
a >= b              ge(a,b)           Greater than or equal to
a ~= b              ne(a,b)           Not equal to
a == b              eq(a,b)           Equality
a & b               and(a,b)          Logical AND
a | b               or(a,b)           Logical OR
~a                  not(a)            Logical NOT
a:d:b               colon(a,d,b)      Colon operator
a:b
colon(a,b)               
a'                  ctranspose(a)     Complex conjugate transpose
a.'                 transpose(a)      Matrix transpose
command line output display(a)        Display method
[a b]               horzcat(a,b,...)  Horizontal concatenation
[a; b]              vertcat(a,b,...)  Vertical concatenation
a(s1,s2,...sn)      subsref(a,s)      Subscripted reference
a(s1,...,sn) = b    subsasgn(a,s,b)   Subscripted assignment
b(a)                subsindex(a)      Subscript index
```

Another good place to look for a list is actually the documentation for [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), which applies any element-wise function with very powerful virtual data replication.

---

Often useful is `vertcat`. [horizontal](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html) vs. [vertical](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) concatenation with a comma separated list:

```
>> c = {'a','b'};
>> horzcat(c{:}) % [c{1} c{2}]
ans =
     ab
>> vertcat(c{:}) % [c{1};c{2}]
ans =
    a
    b
```

---

In addition to many other documented operators with named functions (`colon`,`transpose`,etc.), there are a couple undocumented ones that you can access with [`builtin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/builtin.html):

*parenthesis*

```
>> x = [4 5 6];
>> builtin('_paren',x,[2 3])  % x([2 3])
ans =
     5     6
```

*curly braces*

```
>> c = {'one','two'};
>> builtin('_brace',c,2)  % c{2}
ans =
two
```

*struct field access (dot)*

```
>> s = struct('f','contents');
>> builtin('_dot',s,'f')  % s.f
ans =
contents
```

*However*, note that the proper and supported way to use `()`, `{}`, or `.` is via [`subsref`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html), `subasgn`, and `subindex`, depending on the context.

These builtins refer to the operators described in `help paren`.  Also explore the punctuation listed in `help punct`.

Comment: Does anybody know why `A .- B` is not defined and instead `bsxfun(@minus, A, B)` has to be used? Is there a possibility to overload/define that operator manually?

Comment: @MarioReutter The `.` operators are just pair-wise, requiring that `A` and `B` have the same dimensions.   With `bsxfun`, it performs on-the-fly replication in singleton dimensions (virtual `repmat`).  These two modes of operation are not analogous.  However, you could probably overload an operator to perform a `bsxfun`, but I would definitely not try to use `.-` since that would imply a different meaning (a nonsensical one however since there is no special meaning to `-` in a matrix context as it is always pairwise except in the case where one argument is a scalar).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's how MATLAB enables operator overloading, by mapping infix operators to named functions.

The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/operators-and-elementary-operations.html) lists (by category) the functions invoked by operators.  And [more here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This [link] (http://nf.nci.org.au/facilities/software/Matlab/techdoc/matlab_prog/ch14_o23.html) list how to overload an operator.