# Can operators be called functions?

Tags: function, operators

[Syntactically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(computer_programming)) speaking operators are usually different from functions. However, in [MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678231/matlab-operators-as-functions) all operators are simply syntactic sugar for function calls.

1. Does this mean that we can call such operators functions? i.e., in the statement `a+b` `+` is a function?
2. Are there programming languages where operators aren't syntactic sugar for calling a function?

Comment: For some languages, using an operator is just syntactic sugar for calling a function (and you can easily define your own operators that way). For other languages, these are separate concepts. And "internally implemented" is a bit vague (and usually not covered by the language specification itself). I think you need to rephrase this question to be less broad/vague/open-ended.

Comment: If by "internally implemented as function" you mean that every operator that appears in source code is translated into something identical or very similar to what you would get for a function call, then no: In Java, for example, you cannot define new operators, and the existing operators compile down into bytecode instructions directly (no extra call stack entries involved).

Comment: @Thilo I have rephrased the question, hopefully, now it is not vague. You have answered the second question. If you could please answer the first question and place an answer, I would be glad to accept your answer.